# Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 installation stuck applying KB2829760

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

The acquiring bar is full but the applying bar does not move from KB2829760. Oddly I checked Windows Log and found some messages saying this KB was successfully installed. If I try to cancel it also gets stuck with the message "Stopping the current session...".

[image]

I run Windows 10.

What can I do to move the installation process forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Disabling AVG antivirus did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with earlier versions.
Removing everything (VS) and installing again fixed the problem for me

Comment: What is that "everything" that you have removed?

Comment: Fresh install. I've read that I should just give it like 6 hours, because it is still trying to download stuff even if it is an ISO without telling you.